# Why \ is used at the end of print statement in python?

Tags: python, syntax

Consider the code:

```
firstName = raw_input("Your fist Name: ")
lastName = raw_input("Your last Name: ")
print "Hello %s, May I call you" \
"Mr. %s?" % (firstName,lastName)
```

In line 3, what is the use of `\` ?

Comment: BTW, according to PEP-0008, doing line continuation with `\` is _not_ recommended. The backslash _has_ to be the last char on the line (just before the newline char), so if a space gets accidentally added after the backslash the line continuation won't work. In all modern versions of Python you can spread any expression over multiple lines by wrapping it in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` tells Python that the statement continues on the next line. So, the `print` statement doesn't end on the first line, it continues on the next.

```
print "Hello %s, May I call you" \
"Mr. %s?" % (firstName,lastName)
```

Is the same as:

```
print "Hello %s, May I call youMr. %s?" % (firstName,lastName)
```

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to do a line break and continue your statement on the next line

Answer (score 1):

The `\` character is used to break up long lines so they're easier to read and manage. The third and fourth lines could have been written as a single line without the `\` instead:

```
print "Hello %s, May I call youMr. %s?" % (firstName,lastName)
```

(note there is no space between "you" and "Mr." in the original post either)

Answer (score 1):

to make you able to spilt a single line of string to many lines.